# \\tsclient share is blank when RDP'ing to remote Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdc

I'm logging into a Windows 2003 system from a Windows 7 workstation using Remote Desktop. I'm aiming to try and copy some files to the server from the client. In the 'local resources' section of the RDC, I've got all the drives ticked so it should be sharing those drives with the remote server.

However, when I log in, none of these shares get mapped, and if I navigate to `\\tsclient`, I just get a blank listing.

What's wrong here? What do I need to enable to allow this functionality to work?

Comment: I've found RDP sometimes just does that, no reason, no idea why, check for firewalls I guess otherwise reboot your client, if that's no good it might need a server reboot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any kind of restrictions on the server that you are remoting into?

Check: Start > Run > tscc.msc

Right click on RDP-Tcp and go to Properties > Client Settings

Make sure that Drive Mapping doesn't have a check in it.

Comment: tscc.msc works on Server 2003. But what's the equivalent of tscc.msc on Server 2012?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this can happen if drive redirection is disabled. To see if that's the case on Windows Server 2012 R2:

1. Run `mmc`.
2. Under File, choose Add/Remove Snap-In.
3. Add the Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) snap-in.
4. Right-click on Resultant Set of Policy and choose "Generate RSoP Data."
5. Choose logging mode and follow the on-screen prompts to select the computer you're interested in. You don't need user policy settings.
6. Navigate to Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Session Host, Device and Resource Redirection.
7. Check whether "Do not allow drive redirection" is listed as Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server 2008 R2:

**Server Manager** > **Remote Desktop Services** > **RD Session Host Configuration**

Right click on **RDP-Tcp Connection** and choose **Properties**.

Click on **Client Settings** tab.

Clear **Drive Mapping** checkbox in list of disabled settings.

Answer (score 1):

- If files *AND* text (eg entire clipboard) isn't working, kill and restart `rdpclip.exe` on the server
- If text copy/paste works, but file transfer doesn't, definitely could be the "**drive redirection**" feature being disabled. Another way of checking that is:

1. `gpedit.msc` (local group policy editor)
2. `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection`
3. *Disable* `Do not allow drive redirection`
4. Re-establish the RDP connection

[image]

> This policy setting specifies whether to prevent the mapping of client
> drives in a Remote Desktop Services session (drive redirection).
>
> By default, an RD Session Host server maps client drives automatically
> upon connection. Mapped drives appear in the session folder tree in
> File Explorer or Computer in the format  on
> . You can use this policy setting to override this
> behavior.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, client drive redirection is not
> allowed in Remote Desktop Services sessions, and Clipboard file copy
> redirection is not allowed on computers running Windows Server 2003,
> Windows 8, and Windows XP.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, client drive redirection is always
> allowed. In addition, Clipboard file copy redirection is always
> allowed if Clipboard redirection is allowed.
>
> If you do not configure this policy setting, client drive redirection
> and Clipboard file copy redirection are not specified at the Group
> Policy level.